# Initialization - Multidimensional Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to C and I am trying to experiment with multi-dimensional arrays. I have the following example where I am trying to initialize a multi-dimensional array:

```
char matrix[5][10];  

matrix[0] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
matrix[1] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
matrix[2] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'};
matrix[3] = {'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1','0'};
matrix[4] = {'J','I','H','G','F','E','D','C','B','A'};
```

At first glance it would appear that this type of declaration would be valid since a multi-dimensional array is an array of arrays; however, this example fails to properly compile and I am not entirely certain as to why.

I am aware that I am able to initialize a multi-dimensional array using the following notation:

```
char matrix2[5][10] =
{
    {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'},
    {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'},
    {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'},
    {'9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1','0'},
    {'J','I','H','G','F','E','D','C','B','A'},
};
```

However, what if I do not know the contents of the array at declaration time and would like to populate this array with data at a later point. I could initialize each individual element as follows:

```
matrix[0][0] = '0';
matrix[0][1] = '1';
matrix[0][2] =  '2';
etc....
```

I am wondering if it somehow possible to declare each array using my original approach:

```
matrix[0] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
matrix[1] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
etc...
```

I tried to use `strcpy` as follows:

```
strcpy(matrix[0], "012345678");
strcpy(matrix[1], "abcdefghi");
```

It appears that this might work if the multi-dimensional array was an array of null-terminated strings, but what would be an equivalent to a multi-dimensional array of integers or other data structures. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between an *initialiser* and an *assignment*. They both are introduced by `=`, but they are syntactically and semantically different.

For an *initializer*, C can deduce the type of the right side of the `=` by the left side type. For an *assignment*, the type must be know with the right side and be *compatible* with the left side (lvalue) type. Most imporatnt here: the compiler has no type information from the lvalue when evaluating the right side (it does not even started the assignment expression at that moment).

An *initialiser* must only be used with a *definition* (you seem to confuse this with *declaration* - pay heed, they are well-defined terms with [different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410632/4774918)). SO once you have complete the *definition*, you cannout use an _initialiser anymore.

Since C99, you can use a compound literal. This is much like a string literal (`"Hello world"`), but you have to tell the compiler its exact type (the string literal's type is given by the `"`). Additionally, C does not allow arrays to be simply assigned like scalars or `struct`s. Thus you have to `memcpy` instead of the assignment:

```
memcpy(matrix[0], (char [10]){ 1,2,3,4, ... }, 10));
```

Note the `(char ...}` part which is the *compound literal*. This is **not** a cast, but tells the compiler which type the object in the curly braces has (here: array of `10` `char`s). A cast OTOH is a *prefix expression* and changess the type of the following expression. Note that you can use a _string literal here instead, but that does obviously not work for other array element types. Also note that for *string literals* you cannot define their length other than providing as many characters. So if you forget two characters, you will invoke *undefined behaviour* for reading outside array boundaries. (Two because of the implicit trailing `'\0'` character).

For the dimensions, you better use symbolic constants, (i.e. macros in C) like `#define ROWS 10` to avoid magic numbers in your code - you have to use these values multiple times.

For an array of pointers, you can use the easier way:

```
matrix[0] = (char [10]){ 1,2,3,4,...};
```

**Warning:** This does not allow to change entries like the first version does, because *literals* must not be written to!

Extra: This version also works for `struct`s (not just pointers to them), because C **does** allow assignments for those. To me, this looks like one of the irregularities of C one has to live with.

Comment: How does it differ from a cast?

Comment: @nerdistcolony: It is not a cast, but belongs to the braces. The contents between the braces is not cast to the given type, but tells the compiler the type of the parentethised(!;-) construct. A cast is an expression.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'm going to have to read up on how C treats initialization and assignment statements.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I edited. Thanks again for the correction. I normally use this with structs only, so I forgot in the first place.

Comment: @Olaf - I tried an example with int pointers and I can't figure out how to make it work. Can you show how I would initialize an array of pointers using that technique?  I tried 'casting' as (int **), (int *), (int *[]) ... nothing worked: http://ideone.com/b6R5cy, also http://ideone.com/b6R5cy

Comment: @nerdistcolony: I wonder a bit: You have the same problem, or is that an alternative account you asked with?

Comment: @nerdistcolony: There is on need to cast. And you should **never** cast just to make the code compile unless you really know **why** you have to and are aware about the implications. Use it as I wrote, just change the type to `int`.

Comment: @nerdistcolony: `int *ar2[3];` `ar2[0] = (int [2]){ 1, 2};`

Comment: @Olaf - I created a new account after seeing BLUEPIXY's comment. I first tried it on the command line of my Mac running cc from the latest version of XCode. Same kind of errors.

Comment: @Olaf - I will have to play with this. Why can't I cast the {} contents as (int *[2})? or pass &a, &b, ...? I guess what you're showing is a way I can assign literal addresses to an array... (elements 0 and 1 of a 3 element array?)

Comment: Please understand that this is no debugging service. However, the two lines I posted in my last comment **do** compile. Note that you (as I stated) need C99 at least. VisualC is **not** compliant, clang and gcc **are**, but you might have to enforce this standard in gcc. Not sure about clang (it will not harm, however). If you still have problems, post a new question with **specific** problem statement and [mcve].

Comment: @GRC: Not, it does not! Please read my answer carefully. You cannot assign an array in C, but have to use `memcpy` as I proposed.

Comment: @Olaf give an example in which it does not give an error :)

Comment: `int ar[2][2]; memcpy(ar[0], (int [2]){ 1,2}, 2 * sizeof(int));`

Comment: @Olaf that is not a line giving me error it is this one `matrix[0] = (char [10]){ 1,2,3,4,...};`

Comment: @GRC: Sorry, but I really have no idea how I can make you clear: I already stated in my answer that this is not possible in C, because you cannot assign arrays. Problem is that the right hand side decays to a pointer to the first element _before_ the assignment expression is processed (this is the reason so many people think an array is the same as a pointer), so the assignment never sees the array actually, but only the pointer. You **have to** use `memcpy`.